# Как отправить уведомление с названием приложения?

Tags: python, уведомления

Я пробовал несколько библиотек(plyer, win10toast) для отправки уведомлений win10, но ни одна из них не давало возможность изменить название приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

уведомление шлет не ваша "программа", а интерпретатор, исполняющий ваш код (т.е. Python).

Изменить вы это не сможете. или смиритесь или компилируйте свой код, тогда отправителем уже будет он

Comment: Ок, понял. Не знал таких тонкостей

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавь параметр в `plyer`'е:

```
plyer.notification.notify(app_name='Имя программы')
```